# ardrone package?

Tags: ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I recieved an AR.Drone for christmas, and I, being an autonomous robotics person, would love to use ROS to program the drone. I realize that its sensors are probably subpar, but I still want to use the stack I found here: http://www.ros.org/news/2010/10/ros-interface-for-the-parrot-ardrone.html

Unfortunately, when I tried to clone the repo with git, it appears to be an empty repository. Has this repository moved? If so, where can I find it? And, do you have any tips for a beginning ros C++ programmer for autonomous drones?

Thanks a ton,
-Hunter Allen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12486/ardrone-package?/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2011-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does appear that that package has disappeared. You should take a look at the [ardrone_brown](http://code.google.com/p/brown-ros-pkg/wiki/ardrone_brown) package from Brown.

They also appear to have a second stack with a controller, localization and planner for the drone.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this package useful and easy to use http://wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-10-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried a few of these, and the best, by far, has been ardrone_autonomy. It's based on the Brown node, but is still being supported:

https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2013-10-14**:
Also, make sure you're using version 2.3.3 of the drone firmware if you go this route.